# Text follows div

Tags: css

Hello its me again i have a problem... You see i got a div inside another div and that div got text in it.. However when i position my second div to the right in my big div the text gets positioned right aswell... And I am not able to move it back with `left:0` it works with `left:-250px` but that aint a good solution.... how should I achieve this?

```css
#spellista {
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 29%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

#first {
  left: 0 !important;
  position: absolute;
}

.second {
  color: red;
}

.third {
  color: blue;
}

#searchBar {
  height: 80%;
  width: 85%;
  background-color: rgba(32, 32, 45, 0.98);
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="searchBar">
  <div id="spellista">
    <ul id='first'>
      <li class="second">MOre TEXT</li>
      <li class="third">TEXT</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have multiple elements with same id, which is not correct. Id must be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove duplicate id's

```css
#spellista {
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 29%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

#first {
  left: 0 !important;
  position: absolute;
}

.second {
  color: red;
}

.third {
  color: blue;
}

#searchBar {
  height: 80%;
  width: 85%;
  background-color: rgba(32, 32, 45, 0.98);
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="searchBar">
  <div id="spellista">
    <div id="spellista1">
      <ul id='first'>
        <li class="second">MOre TEXT</li>
        <li class="third">TEXT</li>
      </ul>
    </div
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: let me change a few things then, wait a sec

Comment: ah nevermind it was the same id thing that messed things upu

Comment: Is this ok now?

Answer (score 0):

**Your css code is Ok , Only change Html Code (you have multiple elements with same id) :**

**Your Code is :**

```
<div id="searchBar">
  <div id="spellista">
    <div id="spellista">
      <ul id='first'>
        <li class="second">MOre TEXT</li>
        <li class="third">TEXT</li>
      </ul>
    </div
  </div>
</div>
```

**Change To :**

```
<div id="searchBar">
  <div id="spellista">

      <ul id='first'>
        <li class="second">MOre TEXT</li>
        <li class="third">TEXT</li>
      </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

**Full code:**

```css
   #spellista{
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 29%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
#first{
left:0 !important;
position:absolute;
}
.second{
color:red;
}
.third{
color:blue;
}
#searchBar{
height:80%;
width:85%; 
background-color:rgba(32, 32, 45, 0.98);
position:fixed;
top: 10%;
left: 0;
z-index:2;
margin: auto;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
border-radius:5px;
z-index:3;
}
```

```html
<div id  ="searchBar">
 <div id  = "spellista">
    
          <ul id = 'first'> 
          <li class = "second">MOre TEXT</li>
          <li class = "third">TEXT</li>
           </ul>
     </div>
     
   
  </div>
```